# In my chat app i have this error java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I making chat app .. and I have this problem when i click in any user to start chat with him. but for first time when i get into chat and i send first message it has been sent "in my firebase i see it"but when i am trying to get chat again this error occur ..

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.learno.SocialApp.ChatActivity$4.onDataChange(ChatActivity.java:157)
```

So, this is my code ..

```
public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Toolbar toolbar;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
ImageView profileTv;
TextView nameTv, userStatusTv;
EditText messageEt;
ImageButton sendBtn;
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference usersDbRef;

ValueEventListener seenListener;
DatabaseReference userRefForSeen;

List<Modelchat> chatList;
AdapterChat adapterChat;

String hisUid;
String myUid;
String hisImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("");
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.chat_RecylerView);
    profileTv = findViewById(R.id.profileTv);
    nameTv = findViewById(R.id.nameTv);
    userStatusTv = findViewById(R.id.userStatusTv);
    messageEt = findViewById(R.id.massageEt);
    sendBtn = findViewById(R.id.sendBtn);

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    hisUid = intent.getStringExtra("hisUid");

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    usersDbRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Users");

    Query userQuery = usersDbRef.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(hisUid);

    userQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String name = "" + ds.child("name").getValue();
                hisImage = "" + ds.child("image").getValue();

                nameTv.setText(name);
                try {
                    Picasso.get().load(hisImage).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_defult_img_face).into(profileTv);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.ic_defult_img_face).into(profileTv);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String message = messageEt.getText().toString().trim();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message)) {
                Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "Cannot send empty message...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                sendMessage(message);
            }
        }
    });
    readMessages();
    seenMessages();
}

private void seenMessages() {
    userRefForSeen = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");
    seenListener = userRefForSeen.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Modelchat chat = ds.getValue(Modelchat.class);
                if (chat.getReceiver().equals(myUid) && chat.getSender().equals(hisUid)) {
                    HashMap<String, Object> hasSeenHashMap = new HashMap<>();
                    hasSeenHashMap.put("isSeen", true);
                    ds.getRef().updateChildren(hasSeenHashMap);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private void readMessages() {
    chatList = new ArrayList<>();
    DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");
    dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            chatList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Modelchat chat = ds.getValue(Modelchat.class);
                if (chat.getReceiver().equals(myUid) && chat.getSender().equals(hisUid) ||
                        chat.getReceiver().equals(hisUid) && chat.getSender().equals(myUid)) {
                    chatList.add(chat);
                }
                adapterChat = new

                        AdapterChat(ChatActivity.this, chatList, hisImage);
                adapterChat.notifyDataSetChanged();
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterChat);
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}


private void sendMessage(String message) {


    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    String timeStamp = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());

    HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("Sender", myUid);
    hashMap.put("receiver", hisUid);
    hashMap.put("message", message);
    hashMap.put("timeStamp", timeStamp);
    hashMap.put("isSeen", false);

    databaseReference.child("Chats").push().setValue(hashMap);

    messageEt.setText("");
}

private void checkuserstatus() {
    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null) {
        myUid = user.getUid();
    } else {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Register.class));
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    checkuserstatus();
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    userRefForSeen.removeEventListener(seenListener);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_logout, menu);
    menu.findItem(R.id.actiob_search).setVisible(false);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.logout) ;
    {
        firebaseAuth.signOut();
        checkuserstatus();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

and this is my Model ..

```
public class Modelchat {
String message,receiver,sender,timestamp;
boolean isSeen;

public Modelchat(){}

public Modelchat(String message, String receiver, String sender, String timestamp, boolean isSeen) {
    this.message = message;
    this.receiver = receiver;
    this.sender = sender;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.isSeen = isSeen;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public String getReceiver() {
    return receiver;
}

public void setReceiver(String receiver) {
    this.receiver = receiver;
}

public String getSender() {
    return sender;
}

public void setSender(String sender) {
    this.sender = sender;
}

public String getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}

public boolean isSeen() {
    return isSeen;
}

public void setSeen(boolean seen) {
    isSeen = seen;
}
```

so this error occur when i get into my users fragment and click into any user to start chat with him ..
any one can help me with that ?

Comment: put less code, show the line where the error is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code `chat.getReceiver()` & `chat.getSender()` are returning `null` values and you have many calls like `chat.getReceiver().equals(myUid)` & `chat.getSender().equals(hisUid)` and all of them can product `NullPointerException`.

So correct `getReceiver()` and `getSender()` codes and make sure they do not return `null` values or check for `null` before calling `equals` on them.

Or change `chat.getSender().equals(hisUid)` to `hisUid.equals(chat.getSender())`
and `chat.getReceiver().equals(myUid)` to `myUid.equals(chat.getReceiver())` if `hisUid` and `myUid` always are not `null`.